# VLC pixelated after installing NVIDIA driver

Tags: nvidia, vlc

I don't know what to do. I installed the NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu and after that it's just pixelated, but with the Videos default program I don't have that problem.

I tried to select another output method from Settings on VLC, unfortunately same result.

What can I do?

Comment: Try disabling Hardware Decoding: Tools --> Preferences --> Inout / Codecs --> Codecs --> Hardware Accelerated decoding --> Disable.

Comment: Cool! Give me a minute and I will write up a formal answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to disable Hardware acceleration in the vlc preferences:

```
Tools > Preferences > Input / Codecs > Codecs  > Hardware Accelerated decoding > Disable
```

Screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: This improved the situation here, but didn't fix it completely. Plus the video feels a bit sluggish now... placebo? A step in the right direction though.

Comment: On the Mint 20.3 Cinnamon, the standard Celluloid application had much better quality of image compared to stock VLC. Setting decoding to "VA-API video decoder via DRM" provided same results as Celluloid and is on par with Disabled configuration.